# Using JQuery to Dynamically Add Checkboxes and Validate them

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a form with two radio buttons, yes and no.

When the yes radio button is selected a set of checkboxes (set A) appears and when no is selected, a different set of checkboxes (Set B) appears on my form.

For either set of checkboxes, A or B, at least one checkbox must be selected.

I must use JQuery to solve this issue.

Currently, I am able to get either set A or B checkboxes to appear, but I am unable to write to validation code to check that at least one checkbox is selected in A or B depending on the yes/no answer.

My intuition was to use a change or click event handler, but that would mean writing event handlers for each checkbox which seems verbose and redundant. Is there a JQuery way to do this efficiently for a group of dynamic checkboxes?

```
<li><span style='color:black;'><strong>1. Yes or No? &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;?</strong><br />
                  <li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="Q1_0" id="Q1_0a" value="yes" /><label for="Q1_0a">     Yes</label></span><br />
                  <li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="Q1_0" id="Q1_0b" value="no" /><label for="Q1_0b">     No</label><br />


               <li class="Q1_Y"><span style='color:black;'><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;If Yes: <br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Select all that apply:</strong><br />
                  <li class="Q1_Y">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="Q2" id="Q2_0" value="Ans1" /><label for="Q2_01">Ans1</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  <li class="Q1_Y">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="Q2" id="Q2_1" value="Ans2" /><label for="Q2_02">Ans2</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  <li class="Q1_Y">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="Q2" id="Q2_2" value="Ans3" /><label for="Q2_03">Ans3</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;


               <li class="Q1_N"><span style='color:black;'><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;If No: <br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Select all that apply:<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Select all that apply:</strong><br />
                  <li class="Q1_N">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="Q3" id="Q3_0" value="Ans1" /><label for="Q3_0">Ans1</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  <li class="Q1_N">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="Q3" id="Q3_1" value="Ans2" /><label for="Q3_1">Ans2</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  <li class="Q1_N">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="Q3" id="Q3_2" value="Ans3" /><label for="Q3_2">Ans3</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery(".Q1_Y").hide();
jQuery(".Q1_N").hide();


jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkboxesQ2", function(value, element) {
    return jQuery('input[name="Q2"]:checked').length > 0;
});

jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkboxesQ3", function(value, element) {
    return jQuery('input[name="Q3"]:checked').length > 0;
});
```

jQuery( "#ddd-form" ).validate( {
        rules: {

```
        Q2_0 : { checkboxesQ2: true },
        Q2_1 : { checkboxesQ2: true },
        Q2_2 : { checkboxesQ2: true },
        Q2_3 : { checkboxesQ2: true },
        Q2_4 : { checkboxesQ2: true },
        Q2_5 : { checkboxesQ2: true },
        Q2_6 : { checkboxesQ2: true },


        Q3_0 : { checkboxesQ3: true },
        Q3_1 : { checkboxesQ3: true },
        Q3_2 : { checkboxesQ3: true },
        Q3_3 : { checkboxesQ3: true },
        Q3_4 : { checkboxesQ3: true },
        Q3_5 : { checkboxesQ3: true },
        Q3_6 : { checkboxesQ3: true },

    },
     messages: {


        Q2_0 : { required: "<span>*</span>" },
        Q2_1 : { required: "<span>*</span>" },
        Q2_2 : { required: "<span>*</span>" },
        Q2_3 : { required: "<span>*</span>" },
        Q2_4 : { required: "<span>*</span>" },
        Q2_5 : { required: "<span>*</span>" },
        Q2_6 : { required: "<span>*</span>" },

        Q3_0 : { required: "<span>*</span>" },
        Q3_1 : { required: "<span>*</span>" },
        Q3_2 : { required: "<span>*</span>" },
        Q3_3 : { required: "<span>*</span>" },
        Q3_4 : { required: "<span>*</span>" },
        Q3_5 : { required: "<span>*</span>" },
        Q3_6 : { required: "<span>*</span>" },
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
    },
    errorElement: "em",
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        console.log("error",error)
        console.log("element",element)
        error.appendTo( element.parents("li").prev("li").find('span') );
    },
```

} );

```
 jQuery('#Q1_0a').click(function(e) {
    jQuery( ".Q1_Y" ).show();
    jQuery( ".Q1_N" ).hide();

    jQuery('[name=Q2_0').rules('add', {
        checkboxes: true,
        messages: { checkboxesQ2: "<span>*</span>" }
    });
    jQuery('[name=Q2_1').rules('add', {
        checkboxes: true,
        messages: { checkboxesQ2: "<span>*</span>" }
    });
    jQuery('[name=Q2_2').rules('add', {
        checkboxes: true,
        messages: { checkboxesQ2: "<span>*</span>" }
    });
    jQuery('[name=Q2_3').rules('add', {
        checkboxes: true,
        messages: { checkboxesQ2: "<span>*</span>" }
    });
    jQuery('[name=Q2_4').rules('add', {
        checkboxes: true,
        messages: { checkboxesQ2: "<span>*</span>" }
    });
    jQuery('[name=Q2_5').rules('add', {
        checkboxes: true,
        messages: { checkboxesQ2: "<span>*</span>" }
    });
    jQuery('[name=Q2_6').rules('add', {
        checkboxes: true,
        messages: { checkboxesQ2: "<span>*</span>" }
    });
    jQuery('[realName=Q3_0').rules('remove','checkboxesQ3');
    jQuery('[realName=Q3_1').rules('remove','checkboxesQ3');
    jQuery('[realName=Q3_2').rules('remove','checkboxesQ3');
    jQuery('[realName=Q3_3').rules('remove','checkboxesQ3');
    jQuery('[realName=Q3_4').rules('remove','checkboxesQ3');
    jQuery('[realName=Q3_5').rules('remove','checkboxesQ3');
    jQuery('[realName=Q3_6').rules('remove','checkboxesQ3');

});

jQuery('#Q1_0b').click(function(e) {
    jQuery( ".Q1_Y" ).hide();
    jQuery( ".Q1_N" ).show();

    jQuery('[name=Q3_0').rules('add', {
        checkboxes: true,
        messages: { checkboxesQ3: "<span>*</span>" }
    });
    jQuery('[name=Q3_1').rules('add', {
        checkboxes: true,
        messages: { checkboxesQ3: "<span>*</span>" }
    });
    jQuery('[name=Q3_2').rules('add', {
        checkboxes: true,
        messages: { checkboxesQ3: "<span>*</span>" }
    });
    jQuery('[name=Q3_3').rules('add', {
        checkboxes: true,
        messages: { checkboxesQ3: "<span>*</span>" }
    });
    jQuery('[name=Q3_4').rules('add', {
        checkboxes: true,
        messages: { checkboxesQ3: "<span>*</span>" }
    });
    jQuery('[name=Q3_5').rules('add', {
        checkboxes: true,
        messages: { checkboxesQ3: "<span>*</span>" }
    });
    jQuery('[name=Q3_6').rules('add', {
        checkboxes: true,
        messages: { checkboxesQ3: "<span>*</span>" }
    });
    jQuery('[realName=Q2_0').rules('remove','checkboxesQ2');
    jQuery('[realName=Q2_1').rules('remove','checkboxesQ2');
    jQuery('[realName=Q2_2').rules('remove','checkboxesQ2');
    jQuery('[realName=Q2_3').rules('remove','checkboxesQ2');
    jQuery('[realName=Q2_4').rules('remove','checkboxesQ2');
    jQuery('[realName=Q2_5').rules('remove','checkboxesQ2');
    jQuery('[realName=Q2_6').rules('remove','checkboxesQ2');
});
```

});

Comment: Hi! Can you please add the code you have working up to this point to make it easier for everyone to help you, which will also get your question answered much faster

Comment: why don't you just add "checked" attribute to your input element which is of type checkbox?

Comment: I *tried* to add my code but for some reason it formatted horribly.  NOTE: Im doing all of this in VIM over an ssh session so my apologies for the awfully formatted code (copy/paste did not work very well)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `some` to check if one is selected:

```
if ($(".setA").some(e => e.is(":checked"))) { /* Checkbox is valid */ }
```

## EDIT

If you want this to happen for any checkbox:

```
$("input").change() {
    //Validation code above for A and B
});
```

Comment: I apologize if this isn't the correct way to fame this. I wanted the validation to trigger on the event that ANY checkbox is checked in either set A or set B.  Is there a JQuery way to have an event listener set up so that code executes when any checkbox in Set A or B is selected?